# JS Lightbox for pictures which I want to link to the article the picture is from

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I'm using WordPress as my CMS and I just downloaded a Lightbox plugin for a photo gallery on one of my pages. It works exactly how I want it to, except for one thing.

After clicking on a thumbnail to get the photo enlarged with a lightbox effect, I want to be able to click on a link to take me to the main article where that picture is from.

I've tried a few ways but the issue which arises is that I can't pass < ?php the_permalink(); ?> through a JavaScript function. How would I go about to accomplish this?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: What's the plug-in? What hook does it use to make the lightbox work?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is have the image link go to some inline content, which contains the image wrapped in the  this is the only way. The lightbox website will have examples of linking inline content, but for every image you will need to generate the inline content, this is the limitations of using a plugin.

If I were in your shoes, I would write a custom modal function, which would take the permalink from an attribute of the image (rel, title, class) and display the larger image linked to the permalink. I am sure you can find a custom modal tutorial, but basically you create a box in your css, which is set to display:none, then when your link(s) is/are clicked, you use jQuery to append one of the boxes to body, append your content into the box, then display it in the center of the screen, using absolute positioning, and opaque to dull everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I know I could try with the inline content method. However isn't that going to cause longer loading times for the page if I have multiple large images&content set to display:none;?

Comment: try putting <?php the_permalink(); ?> inside the element being lightboxed (the thumbnail a or img element being clicked)